# How to show the input id or label in validation messages?

Tags: jsf-2, bean-validation

I'm doing a Web application using Spring 3.1.0.RELEASE, JSF 2.x, JPA 2 with Hibernate Provider. The application run on Tomcat 6.X.

The web-app can be show in different languages : en , es , fr.

I use the bean validation in my entities. Hibernate Validator is the provider, version 4.2.0.Final.

```
<h:form id="SiteCreationForm">
            <pou:messages />
            <pou:fieldset legend="#{messages['siteCreation.detail']}">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <h:outputLabel for="siteVisualId" value="#{messages['siteCreation.url']} :" />
```

pou is primefaces

In my entity, I have this:

```
@Size(max = 20)
    @NotBlank
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "visual_id", length = 20, unique = true)
    private String visualId;
```

I don't know why but the error message display only the "may not be empty", its doesn't display the input id or the label . Why, how can I fix this ?

The same happen with the required attribute on input.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the JSF validation message bundle which you specified (or need to specify) in `<message-bundle>` of `faces-config.xml`, add the following entry:

```
javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator.MESSAGE = {1}: {0}
```

The `{0}` is the message of the bean validator and the `{1}` is the label of the JSF component.